# CSS how to force divs to move fluidly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code:

```js
/* Made with love by @fitri
 This is a component of my ReactJS project
 https://codepen.io/fitri/full/oWovYj/ */

function enableDragSort(listClass) {
  const sortableLists = document.getElementsByClassName(listClass);
  Array.prototype.map.call(sortableLists, (list) => {enableDragList(list)});
}

function enableDragList(list) {
  Array.prototype.map.call(list.children, (item) => {enableDragItem(item)});
}

function enableDragItem(item) {
  item.setAttribute('draggable', true)
  item.ondrag = handleDrag;
  item.ondragend = handleDrop;
}

function handleDrag(item) {
  const selectedItem = item.target,
        list = selectedItem.parentNode,
        x = event.clientX,
        y = event.clientY;
  
  selectedItem.classList.add('drag-sort-active');
  let swapItem = document.elementFromPoint(x, y) === null ? selectedItem : document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
  
  if (list === swapItem.parentNode) {
    swapItem = swapItem !== selectedItem.nextSibling ? swapItem : swapItem.nextSibling;
    list.insertBefore(selectedItem, swapItem);
  }
}

function handleDrop(item) {
  item.target.classList.remove('drag-sort-active');
}

(()=> {enableDragSort('drag-sort-enable')})();
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  margin: 20px auto 0;
  max-width: 500px;
  word-wrap:break-word
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #136a8a;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #267871, #136a8a);
background: linear-gradient(to right, #267871, #136a8a);
  color: #fff;
  list-style: none;
}

li.drag-sort-active {
  background: transparent;
  color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #4ca1af;
}

span.drag-sort-active {
  background: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3>Drag and Sort :</h3>
  <div class="drag-sort-enable">
  </div>
  <hr>
  <ul class="drag-sort-enable">
    <li>Application</li>
    <li>Blank</li>
    <li>Class</li>
    <li>Data</li>
    <li>Element</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When a sortable item is dragged on top of another, it slides out of the way to make space for that element to land. Is there a css class or some js code I can add that will force the lis to be animated so that they take a little time moving, making it look fluid?

If not, How would I go about achieving this with us code?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is there any resource, gif or site where you saw that behavior? If you show us the intended animation we could help you better. I am not sure I've understood.

Comment: Like how these tabs move: https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/TabPanel/SortableClosableTabs/jQuery/Light/